# What does CollectionsKt.removeAll do?

Tags: kotlin

I'm converting some kotlin code to java.

I have

```
import kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt; 
...
CollectionsKt.removeAll(x, y);
```

I don't find the kotlin documentation very useful however - i can see that this

> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in the specified collection.

But I am unsure if the operation, at the end, leaves

1. x less anything in y.
2. y less anything in x.

What is the action here?

Comment: This is actually the implementation of the extension function MutableCollection.removeAll(). You're not supposed to call it that way, but instead as if it was an instance method of MutableCollection: mutableCollection.removeAll(otherCollection)

Comment: this looks like Java, you won't import `CollectionsKt` in Kotlin code

Comment: just use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 0):

`kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt` is that Java class for interoperability by Kotlin.
In Kotlin, you should use `x.removeAll(y)` instead.

removeAll is a extension function, see the [documentation on it](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/remove-all.html)

From the documentation :

> Removes all of this collection's elements that are also contained in the specified collection.

It will return x with every content of y removed from it.

---

Coming back to CollectionsKt.removeAll, you can use it in your kotlin code although it shoudln't be used, where x is the collection on which it is executed. So it will return x minus the contents of y.